# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing and TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'vanilla_or_ball'

Tags: python, knn

I'm trying to test the best hyperparameter pairs of my training and validation sets for the white wine quality dataset. After implementing this code:

```
    # test the hyperparameter pairs
    best_loss = 5555
    best_p = 5555
    
    training_list = []
    validation_list = []
    
    for k in k_values:
        # Create a classifier: a support vector machine classifier
        # Learn the digits on the train subset
        clf = KNN(k, vanilla_or_ball='vanilla')
        clf.fit(X_train, Y_train) 
    
        # Predict the value of the digit on data
        for d in distances:
          predicted_train = clf.predict(X_train, d)
          predicted_valid = clf.predict(X_valid, d)
    
        # evaluate the loss
        loss_0_1_valid = np.mean(predicted_valid != Y_valid)
        loss_0_1_train = np.mean(predicted_train != Y_train)
    
        if loss_0_1_valid < best_loss:
            best_loss = loss_0_1_valid
            best_k = k
            best_distance = d
    
        print('k: {}   metric    training loss: {:.4f}     validation loss: {:.4f}'.format(k, d, loss_0_1_train, loss_0_1_valid))
    
    training_list = [round(num, 4) for num in training_list]
    validation_list = [round(num, 4) for num in validation_list]
    print('List of training losses: ' + str(training_list))
    print('List of validation losses: ' + str(validation_list)
```

I get the errors that are in my title

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

and

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'vanilla_or_ball'
```

Comment: You're missing a `)` on the last line.

Comment: ... and you didn't share full working code, so it's unclear where `KNN` is coming from, but clearly its constructor doesn't like `vanilla_or_ball` as a keyword argument.

Comment: Hi @Caroline, welcome to Stack Overflow. Take the [tour] if you haven't yet. It's a bit unusual that you're reporting two different errors in the same block of code. Normally the interpreter would stop after the first error and so you wouldn't see another, even if there was a second error. Can you clarify how you're seeing these error messages? Are they messages from your IDE, or are you running the code before you see them? Where in the code are the exceptions being raised? Can you give the full traceback of the exceptions?